# How to collapse/expand widget code region/area in Compose Android Studio like in XML

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have many Composables and I want to collapse Composable code inside like in `xml`. Is there extension for that?

Comment: AFAIK, you should be able to collapse Kotlin code by using the same keyboard shortcut as you would to collapse your XML layouts - see the [code folding IntelliJ IDEA docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding) for more info

Comment: @Edric folding not work in composables

Comment: @AdelAyman, I modified your question's title since your'e asking for folding/collapse/expand of codes like in XML, which you mentioned in your post body, not an actual collapsible/expandable widget/ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post title is a bit misleading, but I think your'e asking how to collapse/expand "code" not the actual widget/ui.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you can expand/collapse a specific area of your code if you wrap them within `region/endregion` without the need of any plugin or configuration, its almost the same behavior that your'e expecting from the xml editor, and you can do this anywhere not only to a function.

expanded code region

[image]

collapsed code region

[image]

Sample Inner composable expanded
[image]

Sample Inner composable collapsed
[image]

[image]

Comment: I mean Folding code Widget Like Text(..........) i want to fold it or collapse code region

Comment: I already mentioned you can do it anywhere not only to a function, I updated my answer and used two `Text` inside a composable function with region/endregion folding

Comment: How do you do that? it not working in my android studio

Comment: Not sure why its not working in your Studio, it should be a default config, make sure every "region" has a matching "endregion" and try to click the +/- button in the left side

Comment: i tried but not work can you please share image of your code folding setting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250057/discussion-between-z-y-and-adel-ayman).

Comment: did it work? thank you for accepting the answer, ticking the upvote button will also be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: @AdelAyman glad to know its finally working! your welcome!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to make your Column collapse or expand without animation you simply need to add a if statement and set true to display false to collapse

var visible by remember {
mutableStateOf(true)
}

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    Text("Click to expand or collapse", modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable {
            visible = !visible
        }
    )
    if(visible) {
      // Content to be collapsed or displayed
    }
}
```

If you wish to collapse or expand with animation you can check out `AnimatedVisbility` composable

```
var visible by remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

    Text("Click to expand or collapse", modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .clickable {
            visible = !visible
        }
    )
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = visible) {
        Column {
          // Content to be collapsed or displayed
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No I talking about the code i want to collapse widget code in ide